# Our app uses: ASP.Net, VB.Net, and Microsoft's AJAX implementation. Is there any unmanaged code in there?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

The middleware that manages talk between the mainframe and our app is blowing up randomly.  It's a "such and such attempted to read/write protected memory..." error.

The vendor is saying there we must be running some unmanaged code (I feel they're trying to worm out of it).  I know VB's entirely managed, but does anyone know about the server portion of AJAX?  Is there any server side javascript stuff that occurs before it actually gets into the .NET framework?

Comment: best bet is too look in the stack trace and see where exactly the application is throwing an exception, otherwise it is a fingers point game

Comment: I bet that memory is being accessed by more than one source simultaneously.

Comment: It's throwing an exception on the vendor's dll.  "System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. at SoftwareAG.EntireX.NETWrapper.Runtime.ERX.Logon(CLIENT_IDENTIFICATION pClient, String szEtbidName) at SoftwareAG.EntireX.NETWrapper.Runtime.Broker.Logon() at ..."  so we know it's their code that's dying.  We've been going around and around for 3 years on this, and now they're trying to blame it on us, but our code is pretty vanilla.

Comment: With a Namespace like SoftwareAG.EntireX.NETWrapper.Runtime, it certainly sounds like they have unmanaged code somewhere - that's almost always why you build a wrapper.  Not to mention their parameter naming convention is from C++.  If you're looking for unmanaged code, I'd look there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the .NET Framework nor its AJAX add-ons contain *server-side* JavaScript.  The .NET Framework does of course contain unmanaged code, and there are rare crashing bugs in it.